# Чем удобно просматривать log-файлы? Можно ли записывать действия пользователя в лог или это неверно?

Tags: python, логирование

Пишу чат-бота на aiogram. Хочу разные действия юзера записывать в лог-файл (logger, logging): когда зарегистрировался, когда совершил какое-то действие и др. И не только пользователей, но и когда запустился сервер и пр.

1. В какой программе это удобно и быстро просматривать? Например найти все действия определенного пользователя...
2. Или правильнее это всё записывать в Базу данных, а не в лог-файл?
   Может быть логи только для ошибок?

Answer (score 0):

Для аудита посмотри graylog, grafana